Equivalent of Discriminant Analysis with Categorical Variables as Predictors
I have a dataset where students vote for a class speaker. This dataset includes the student's id, the class speaker that he/she is voting for, and his/her sociodemographic characteristics (gender, age, country of origin).
I want to know which variables help me discriminate more between students who vote for class speaker A vs other class speakers. In canonical discriminant analysis, this is easy to do with numerical predictor variables. How can I do this with categorical predictor variables?
If I use multiple logistic regression, I can only interpret pairwise comparison...

First... your last statement is incorrect. You can look at the parameter estimates and standard errors to see which variables are helping distinguish.
Second, you can use trees. Tree diagrams are very easy to interpret.
Random forests may also be helpful
